# event after asyn function finished in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, types

hi i made a simple ionic app to connect to an api as the instruction at here :
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-your-first-ionic-4-app-with-api-calls-f6ea747dc17a/
u have a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MovieService {
  url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/';
  apiKey = '';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  searchData(title: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?s=${encodeURI(title)}&apikey=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
      map(results => results['Search'])
    );
  }
}
```

also I have another page.ts which works like this:

```
import { MovieService, SearchType } from './../../services/movie.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.page.scss'],
})
export class MoviesPage implements OnInit {

  results: Observable<any>;
  searchTerm: string = '';
  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  doSearch() {
    this.results = this.movieService.searchData(this.searchTerm);
  }
}
```

how can I launch an event like for example navigate to another page  when doSearch finished it's job?

because if i use like this:

```
doSearch() {
 this.results = this.movieService.searchData(this.searchTerm);
 alert("fin");
}
```

the alert show up although the result job is still working

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make desirable changes inside subscribe method.

```
 doSearch() {  
              this.movieService.searchData(this.searchTerm).subscribe(result 
                  => {
                       alert("fin");
                      });        
          }
```

Comment: i got error:
`
 [ng]     ERROR in src/app/newcheck/newcheck.page.ts(32,3): error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
[ng]     src/app/newcheck/newcheck.page.ts(33,19): error TS1200: Line terminator not permitted before arrow.
`

Comment: Edited answer now . and I can't see there any error code regarding above code

Comment: oh i uploaded a wrong image:here is the correct one https://imgur.com/FU2r83e